# Changing an Image on TouchesBegan

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimageview

Hey, I am trying to change the image when the user touches the ImageView. At the moment the ImageView has the image "heart1.png" so when i touch the ImageViewer on screen it will change to "heart2.png" this is my code, help is much appreciated:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if (location.x >= imageView.frame.origin.x && location.x <= imageView.frame.origin.x + imageView.frame.size.height && location.y >= imageView.frame.origin.y && location.y <= imageView.frame.origin.y + imageView.frame.size.height) {
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"heart2.png"];
    }    
}
```

Comment: What works? What doesn't? What is your question?

Comment: not Xcode-related. Xcode is just an IDE

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a problem to me:

if (location.x >= imageView.frame.origin.x && location.x <= imageView.frame.origin.x + imageView.frame.size.**--> height <--**

should be width there probably :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fool around with checking coordinates against a bounding rect, why don't you simplify things by using interface building to place a custom (i.e. invisible) UIButton right over the image? Then you can hook up `touchesUpInside` to an IBAction method. Then there's no awkward if statements in your code and less chance of making mistakes like this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an UIButton instead.

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart2.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to find location of `view`, You don't have to do move `UIImageView`. Simply do this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    // imageView is your UIImageView
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart1.png"]];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    // Make sure userInteractionEnable is set to be YES; otherwise the touch event will be happen on UIView not on ImageView;
   [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    if([touch view]==imageView)
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart2.png"]];
}
```